# XNA, Create a blob'ish circle with texture?

Tags: c#, xna, farseer

a couples days ago i started experimenting with Farseer, which is a simple and awesome engine in my opinion.

However, now i want to create a blob like Circle for one of my 2D game but i can't seem to figure out to do it and how to use texture with it.

By blob like i mean like a tenis ball or stress ball that we can squeeze for example.

Could anyone point me to the right direction please? I am sorry i haven't tried anything, i have absolutly no clue where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out: http://box2d.org/manual.html :Exactly the same like Farseer, they recommend it in their documentation.

I never used this engine before, but I would imagine you would need to combine joints, bones, etc to create a circle.